# Installing executable scripts with R package

Tags: r, deployment, package, executable

In most scripting languages (e.g. Ruby, Python, etc.) the package manager (e.g. gem, pip, etc.) can install scripts as executables and link them to a directory referenced in the PATH variable (e.g. /usr/local/bin). This turns those executable scripts into shell commands that the user can run in an standalone manner and outside the programming interface.

I wonder if there is such a possibility in R as well. Given that R uses standard Makefiles, I guess there must be a way to do so, albeit a non-standard one. I already know we can read command line arguments in a R script [using the `docopt` package](http://www.jonzelner.net/statistics/make/docker/reproducibility/2016/05/31/script-is-a-program/). But is there a way to install the script as an executable upon the installation of a package?

It would be great to have a lead on this topic, but a single working example from CRAN would suffice as well.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the `system.file()` function? It can locate a file embedded within an installed R package

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short (and very sad) answer: You cannot. But read on.

Reasoning: R will only ever write package content to its own `.libPaths()` directory (or the first in case several are given), or a directory given by the user.

So, say, `/usr/local/bin/` is simply out of reach.  That is a defensible strategy.

It is also rather sad--I wrote [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) (also [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/package=littler)) for exactly this purpose: *executable R scripts*.  And we have *dozens* of those at work called from `cron` jobs.  So what do we do?  A *one-time* soft-link from the `scripts/` subdirectory of the package containing the script to `/usr/local/bin`.  At package upgrades, the link persists as a soft-link.

And that's what I do for *e.g.* all the [examples shipping with littler](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/tree/master/inst/examples) and more from other packages. Many of them use [docopt](https://cran.r-project.org/package=littler) too.

Comment: But is there a standard bin path under R's `.libPaths()` that we can add to the path once for all, and then link all our executables there? That's how `pip` and `gem` function.

Comment: Just expand `.libPaths()`: it is one level _above_ all the package directories.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar goal, this was the solution I settled on. I added a function to my R package that goes through and (verbosely) creates symlinks from `~/.local/bin` to each script in my packages `exec` folder.

Other sensible default locations might be `~/.local/lib/R/bin` or `~/bin`, but I like `~/.local/bin` the best.

So after installing the package, I direct users to run

```
Rscript -e 'mypackage::install_executable_scripts()'
```

```
#' @export
install_executable_scripts <- function(into = "~/.local/bin", overwrite = FALSE) {
  scripts <- dir(system.file("exec", package = "mypackage"),
                 full.names = TRUE)
  if (!dir.exists(into)) dir.create(into)
  into <- normalizePath(into)

  dests <- file.path(normalizePath(into), basename(scripts))
  if (any(already_exist <- file.exists(dests))) {
    if (overwrite) {
      to_del <- dests[already_exist]
      cli::cat_bullet("Deleting existing file: ", to_del,
                      bullet_col = "red")
      unlink(to_del)
    } else {
      cli::cat_bullet(sprintf(
        "Skipping script '%s' because a file by that name already exists at the destination",
        basename(scripts[already_exist])))
      scripts <- scripts[!already_exist]
      dests   <-   dests[!already_exist]
    }
  }
  if (length(scripts)) {
    file.symlink(scripts, dests)
    cli::cat_line("Created symlinks:")
    cli::cat_bullet(dests, " ->\n    ", scripts, bullet_col = "green")
  } else
    cli::cat_line("Nothing installed")

  PATHS <- normalizePath(strsplit(Sys.getenv("PATH"), ":", fixed = TRUE)[[1]],
                         mustWork = FALSE)
  if(!into %in% PATHS)
    warning(sprintf("destination '%s' is not on the PATH", into))
}
```